# Libgdx: Animating line drawing

Tags: libgdx

I want to draw a big V on the game screen (0,0) to (45,45) to (90,0).
But I also want it to animate when the line is drawn.
Below is the pseudo code. But I guess there is a better way to achieve this because I need to draw about 50 V with different sizes.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

//drawing method
if( x <= 45 && y <= 45 ){
    x++;
    y++;
    draw line from 0,0 to x,y
}else if( x <= 90 && y >= 0 ){
    x++;
    y- -;
    draw another line from 45,45 to x,y
}
```

Comment: Are you interested in line drawing methods in LibGDX (e.g. [ShapeRenderer.line](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html)) and how to use them, or a way to draw 50 V in different sizes?

Comment: @bal Currently I'm able to draw the line using ShapeRenderer. I would like to know if there a better way to draw the 50 V in different sizes with animation.